# App on google play not showing on some android device

Tags: android, google-play

I published my application yesterday. After a few hours I check on the Google Play website using Firefox and it was there. I checked it and downloaded it onto my Sony Ericsson Xperia handset. But two of my friends who uses Samsung Galaxy handsets do not see it published on Google Play.

Everytime I check the name it shows 0 results?

Is there something wrong with the way I published the app?

Please tell me. Thanks

Comment: not in android market.. please read my post. it is showing on android market but not on some android device

Comment: Check your `AndroidManifest.xml` to see if it does indeed support various screen sizes (hdpi, mdpi and ldpi)? Also, what SDK did you build your app against? Always target minimum SDK to 7 or 8 (Eclair/Froyo respectively) and target maximum SDK to 16 to ensure wide scope for devices.

Comment: Yes it support different screen sizes. here http://pastebin.com/qRgdbmcy please check my manifest..

Comment: And what SDK did you build it against?

Comment: @tom no i didnt put target. i just include maximum and minimum sdk.

Comment: @t0mm13b If the minimum SDK is larger than the phone SDK, will it just not show up in the play store itself? Also, would these permissions be good? Do I need to add anything? 
http://snag.gy/Bo7Cv.jpg

Answer (score 0):

a friend of mine also has the same problem. however i dont what she did. here check this.. http://developer.coronalabs.com/forum/2011/10/25/app-not-showing-android-market-search-all I hope it helps.. goodluck

Ow ow.. w8. I think your problem was you access the different icon on your friends android device. Maybe you access the app stroe not the google play icon. please check it.

Comment: @thenewbie What was the problem?